# how to append an iframe or object with external source to website?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm working on a Chrome extension which appends `script` and `iframe` (or `object`) to the active tab.

Appending scripts and images with an external link in `background.js` works fine using following piece of code:

```
var appender = "var scr= document.createElement('script'); scr.src= 'https://google.com/boo.js'; document.body.appendChild(scr);";

chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
  chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, { code: appender });
});
```

but using the same code I'm unable to add `iframe` or `object` element. This is the error I get every single time:

> Refused to load the iframe 'https://website.com' because it violates
>   the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-src 'self'
>   'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' assets-cdn.github.com".

My question is, how can I add an external `iframe` or `object` to the current tab?